# Why there is no data successfully inserted when using insertTablet in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

Are there an example of how to use insertTablet in Apache IoTDB? I tested it and found that it didn’t work. The execution process is very fast, but no data is successfully inserted. At first I thought it was because I did not add bitmap, but adding it didn't seem to have any effect. I don’t know what’s going on, so are there any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the Apache IoTDB github and see if the tree/master/example/session/src/main/java/org/apache/iotdb folder offers the example you want.